# Delete Azure B2C AD Tenant

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to delete my azure AD tenant, but it says:

> Directory has one or more applications.

I followed the steps here

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2967860/you-can-t-delete-a-directory-through-the-azure-management-portal

and here

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgolpe/2015/04/30/walkthrough-of-deleting-an-azure-ad-tenant/

`Get-MsolServicePrincipal` returns no added applications.

I notice that App Registrations says 1 in the Azure portal, yet clicking on it the list is blank. Can you query the Registered applications some other way?

Comment: Have you read `How do I delete my Azure AD B2C tenant?` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs?

Comment: Ah, I had not seen that, thanks. There was an application registered in the B2C blade, which I have now deleted. However now when I go to delete my tenant, it has a grey rain cloud, and attempting to delete in the old portal says "Could not validate this directory for deletion." with no further information!

Comment: Is there any application when you using the `Get-AzureRmADApplication` command to query the Azure B2C Active Directory?

Comment: did you delete "b2c-extensions-app" from Applications tab from "manage.windowsazure.com"? This app available under Applications and from dropdown "Applications my company owns"

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT Nope, it returns nothing!

Comment: @Ramakrishna Yeah, all apps are deleted.

Comment: Now when I'm in the portal I just get the rain cloud when on the AD blade, and a shed load of 400 errors with stack traces from MS Azure. Seems I broke it some how! :(

Comment: I raised a support issue with MS, did their live chat thingy. Now it's broken even further, being escalated right now. http://i.imgur.com/iDLTLEj.png ... and now my subscription account is a guest account in it and although it is set as a global admin it doesn't show up in my tenants list any more...  There's no way to access the blade to re-set guest permissions to have the same permissions as users either, which may have helped lol!

Answer (score 1):

When you go to the **App Registations** blade, make sure you're filtering for "All Apps", not just "My Apps" (which is the default). Gets me every time!!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1enx.png]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where the application list was showing there weren't any applications to remove when trying to delete the directory.

However, in the Azure B2C blade, in the Portal and found that I could still go to Applications there.  I still had an application there (even though the b2c extension had been removed) that I removed.

After waiting a couple minutes, it then stopped saying that I still had an application and I could delete the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I created a directory for b2c testing but wasn't able to delete due to app registrations weirdness. I found that there was an invisible app registration that didn't show up in the portal but stopped me deleting the dir (even when viewing 'all apps').

If you get in the same situation you can delete it using the azure cli as follows:
(use --allow-no-subscriptions if you don't have any subs in the dir)

```
az login -t <tenant-id> --allow-no-subscriptions
az ad app list
az ad app delete --id <invisible-app-id>
```

Hope this helps someone!